Hint for a combinatorial proof of $n! \binom{n-1}{k-1} = \sum_{j=0}^n \overline{s}_{n,j} \tilde{S}_{j,k}$
To clarify notation, we have $\overline{s}_{n,j}$ the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind, meaning the number of permutations on an set with $n$ elements that has exactly $j$ cycles. $\tilde{S}_{j,k}$ are the number of surjections from a set with $j$ elements onto a set with $k$ Elements.
I already have a proof using complete induction together with the recurrence relations
$$\overline{s}_{n,j} = \overline{s}_{n-1,j-1} + \overline{s}_{n-1,j}$$
and
$$ \tilde{S}_{j,k} = k \cdot (\tilde{S}_{j-1,k} + \tilde{S}_{j-1,k-1})$$
The proof is straight forward with induction, but I would like to have a hint to prove it combinatorially.
On the left hand side we have the number of the partitions of simple words over an alphabet of cardinality $n$ of length $n$ into $k$  (simple) subwords.  On the right hand side we have the sum of the number of permutations with $j$ cycles times the numbers of surjections from an set with $j$ elements onto a set with $k$ elements.
I don't really have an intuition for what the $j$ stands. As the only thing that varies in the partition is the length of the subwords i would guess it has something to do with the length of the subwords. And I don't see the intuition behind the product. I guess the surjections act on the cycles, so that every cycle is mapped to a subword, and the permutation acts on the alphabet, so we get every possible simple word.
So heuristically speaking we split up our alphabet into $j$ cycles and than put the $j$ cycles into the $k$ subwords (we might put several into the same). But I don't see yet why this gives us all partitions exactly once.

Hint:
It is good to think as you did, about taking a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$, writing it in one-line notation, then inserting dividers at $k-1$ places to split this into $k$ sublists. Now, you know from the RHS that we are going to end up with a finer subdivision, of $[n]$ into $j$ cycles. So, one thing we could do is view these sublists as permutations themselves (on a subset of $[n]$), and use this to break them into cycles.
Solution:

 On the RHS, we start with the factor of $\overline{s}_{n,j}$, which signifies choosing a permutation of $[n]$ which has $j$ cycles, for some $j\ge k$. We then have the factor $S_{j,k}$, which means we assign each of these cycles a number from $1$ to $k$ such that each number appears at least once. Now, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$, let $S_i$ be the (nonempty) set of cycles labeled $i$. $S_i$ is a collection of cycles $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_r$ (for some $r$), where the supports of $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_r$ are pairwise distjoint subsets $[n]$. Therefore, $S_i$ uniquely determines a permutation $\pi_i$, where the domain of $\pi_i$ is the union of the supports of $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_r$ in $S_i$.

 On the LHS, you take a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$, write it in one-line notation, then insert dividers at $k-1$ places to split $\pi$ into $k$ nonempty sublists. Each sublist determines a permutation, $\pi_i$, on the set of its elements (not in a really natural way, but there are clearly $s!$ orderings for every sublist consisting of $s$ elements). Therefore,  each sublist can be split up into cycles, corresponding to the cycles of $\pi_i$. Say that the total number of cycles among these $k$ permutations is $j$; note that each cycle comes with a label from $1$ to $k$, according to which sublist the cycle came from, and the assignment from cycles to $\{1,\dots,k\}$ is surjective.

 On both the RHS and LHS, we have come up with identical combinatorial interpretations. Both describe the number of ways to partition $[n]$ into subsets, put a cycle structure on each subset, and then assign each cycle a number from $\{1,\dots,k\}$ surjectively.

